# Issue in calling validator automic with @Valid in Spring controller

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am trying to call validator from controller using @Valid annotation, but control is not going to validator and proceeding without validating.

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/event")
public class EventController {

@Autowired
private EventService eventService;

@Autowired
EventValidator eventValidator;

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(eventValidator);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add_event",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<AjaxJSONResponse> postAddEventForm(@Valid @RequestPart("event") Event event, MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    Boolean inserted = eventService.addEvent(event);
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    String redirectURL = StringUtils.isEmpty(contextPath)?"/event":contextPath+"/event";
    return new ResponseEntity<AjaxJSONResponse>(new AjaxJSONResponse(inserted,"Event Added Successfully",redirectURL), HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

Validator

```
@Component
public class EventValidator implements Validator  {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Event.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Event event = (Event)target;

    if (event.getEventName() == null ||!StringUtils.hasText(event.getEventName())) {
        errors.rejectValue("eventName", "", "Event Name is empty");
    }
}
}
```

Please help on this.

Thank in advance

Comment: `@Valid` only works on `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` not on `@RequestPart`.

Comment: I tried with `@ModelAttribute` but it is not working for that also.

Comment: You cannot just change it to `@ModelAttribute`. Read some documentation of what to use when and how to use it. I even doubt the method will get triggered.

Comment: I checked that we can use `@Valid` for `@RequestPart` also and that is handled by spring using `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver` class, by function `validateIfApplicable`

Comment: The actual issue was Validator was not binding because of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372252/spring-autowired-bean-giving-null)